# scrollSpy with vanilla js, the code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, api, dom

```
<aside class="panel">
    <nav class="menu">
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion1">Reloj Digital y Alarma sonora</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion2">Eventos de Teclado</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion3">Countdown</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion4">Responsive con Js</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion5">Responsive Tester</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion6">Deteccion de Dispositivos(user agent)</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion7">Deteccion del estado  de la red</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion8">Deteccion de dispositivos de entrada</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion9">Geolocalizacion</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion10">Filtro de busqueda</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion11">Sorteo Digital</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion12">Responsive Slider</a>
        <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion13">ScrollSpy</a>
    </nav>
</aside>  
<main>
    <section id="seccion1" class="section">
    <section id="seccion2" class="section"> 
    <section id="seccion3" class="section">
    <section id="seccion4" class="section">
</main>
```

```
.active{
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--second-color);
}
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const scrollSpy = () => {
        const targets= document.querySelectorAll('.section');
        const options = {
            threshold: 0.5,
        };
    
        if('IntersectionObserver' in window){
         ()=> {
            const inView = target => {
                const interSecObs = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
                    entries.forEach(entry => {
                        const elem = entry.target;
                        let currentNav = document.querySelector(`.panel .menu .menu-item a[href='#${elem.id}']`);
                        (entry.isIntersecting) ? currentNav.classList.add('active') : currentNav.classList.remove('active')
                    })
                }, options);
                interSecObs.observe(target)
            };
            targets.forEach(inView);
         }   
        }
    }
    
})
```

> I am trying to scroll spy with vanilla js, but the code dont work and i dont understand why. I need the styles of the nav to change using the IntersectionObserver API.
> I have checked the code and I can not find what is wrong

Answer (score 2):

I've noted several errors / typos

1. you never call `scrollSpy()`
2. right after `if('IntersectionObserver' in window){` you create a function which is never called. I've removed it.
3. `currentNav` the selector should be `.panel .menu .menu-item[href='#${elem.id}']` no space between `.menu-item` and `[href='#${elem.id}']` no need the `a`. Note that it would probably work as well with only `[href='#${elem.id}']`
4. I've simplified

```
(entry.isIntersecting) ? currentNav.classList.add('active') : currentNav.classList.remove('active')
```

by

```
currentNav?.classList.toggle('active', entry.isIntersecting);
```

I've changed the CSS to make the snippet worked but this is not part of the answer.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const scrollSpy = () => {
    const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
    const options = {
      threshold: 0.5,
    };

    if ('IntersectionObserver' in window) {
      /* 2 */ // () => {…
      const inView = target => {
        const interSecObs = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
          entries.forEach(entry => {
            const elem = entry.target;
            /* 3 */ const currentNav = document.querySelector(`[href='#${elem.id}']`);
            /* 4 */ currentNav?.classList.toggle('active', entry.isIntersecting);
          })
        }, options);
        interSecObs.observe(target)
      };
      targets.forEach(inView);

    }
  };

  /* 1 */ scrollSpy();

})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu-item {
  display: block;
}

main {
  overflow: auto;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.active {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<aside class="panel">
  <nav class="menu">
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion1">Reloj Digital y Alarma sonora</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion2">Eventos de Teclado</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion3">Countdown</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion4">Responsive con Js</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion5">Responsive Tester</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion6">Deteccion de Dispositivos(user agent)</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion7">Deteccion del estado de la red</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion8">Deteccion de dispositivos de entrada</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion9">Geolocalizacion</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion10">Filtro de busqueda</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion11">Sorteo Digital</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion12">Responsive Slider</a>
    <a class="menu-item" href="#seccion13">ScrollSpy</a>
  </nav>
</aside>
<main>
  <section id="seccion1" class="section"></section>
  <section id="seccion2" class="section"></section>
  <section id="seccion3" class="section"></section>
  <section id="seccion4" class="section"></section>
</main>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i will try to fix the code with your suggestions.